# Multiply columns values by a scalar based on conditions DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, multiple-columns

I want to multiply column values by a specific scalar based on the name of the column:

- if column name = "Math", then all the values in 'Math" column should be multiply by 5;
- if column name = "Physique", values in that column should be multiply by 4;
- if column name = "Bio", values in that column should be multiplied by 3;
- all the remaining columns should be multiplied by 2

What I have:

[image]

This is what I should have :

[image]

```
listm = ['Math', 'Physique', 'Bio']
def note_coef(row):
    for m in listm:
        if 'Math' in listm:
             result = df['Math']*5
    return result

df2=df.apply(note_coef)
df2
```

Note I stopped with only 1 if to test my code but the outcome is not what I expected. I am quite new in programming and here as well.

Comment: Please don’t post images of the data as we can’t test them. Instead, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), by sharing a sample of the DataFrame(s) and the expected output within a code block along with the description of the problem. This allows us to easily reproduce your problem and help you. This should help: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Sorry about that. As I am new, I have to learn how to post a question as requested by the site. I will try my best next time. Thank you.

Comment: No worries, I understand that, we've all been there ;) It's just for future reference. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most elegant solution is to define a dictionary (or a `pandas.Series`) with the multiplying factor for each column of your DataFrame (`factors`). Then you can multiply all the columns with the corresponding factor simply using `df *= factors`.

The multiplication is done via column axis alignment, i.e. by aligning the `df.columns` with the dictionary keys.

For instance, given the following DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones(shape=(4, 5)), columns=['Math', 'Physique', 'Bio', 'Algo', 'Archi'])

>>> df

   Math  Physique  Bio  Algo  Archi
0   1.0       1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0
1   1.0       1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0
2   1.0       1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0
3   1.0       1.0  1.0   1.0    1.0
```

You can do:

```
factors = {'Math': 5, 'Physique': 4, 'Bio': 3}
default_factor = 2

factors.update({col: default_factor for col in df.columns if col not in factors})

df *= factors

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Math  Physique  Bio  Algo  Archi
0   5.0       4.0  3.0   2.0    2.0
1   5.0       4.0  3.0   2.0    2.0
2   5.0       4.0  3.0   2.0    2.0
3   5.0       4.0  3.0   2.0    2.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was loking for. Can you explain what dows this code do? factors.update({col: default_factor for col in df.columns if col not in factors}).

Comment: However, i noticed (1) the firts column of my data frame which is a str is also multiply by the default_factor; (2) values in my data frame keeps changing as long as you run the code. 
I'd like the code to run just one time no matter how many time it is executed.
Here is the code I figured
coefi = [1,5, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2]
df_coefi = df[['Nom Etudiant','Math', 'Physique', 'Bio', 'Algo', 'Archi', 'Sport',
       'Ang']] * coefi

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df['col_name'].multiply(value)` to apply on a whole column. The remaining columns can be modified in a loop of all columns except `listm`.

```
listm = ['Math', 'Physique', 'Bio']
for i, head in enumerate(listm):
    df[head] = df[head].multiply(5-i)

heads = df.head()
for head in heads:
    if not head in listm:
        df[head] = df[head].multiply(2)
```

Comment: Hello AboAmmar; thank you for your response. My question is, what if, the scalar are not 5, 4, 3? They can be any int actually.

Answer (score 0):

Fake data

```
n=5
d = {'a':np.ones(n),
     'b':np.ones(n),
     'c':np.ones(n),
     'd':np.ones(n)}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)
```

Select the columns and multiply by a tuple.

```
df[['a','c']] = df[['a','c']] * (2,4)
print(df)
```

---

```
     a    b    c    d
0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
3  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0

     a    b    c    d
0  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
1  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
2  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
3  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
4  2.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to do it using array multiplication

The data was not provided as a text, so created the test data in a patter of the screen shot

```
mul = [5,4,3,2,2,2,2,1]  # multipliers

df1=df.iloc[:,1:].mul(mul)
df1.total = df1.iloc[:,:7].sum(axis=1)
df.update(df1, join='left', overwrite=True)
df
```

```
    source  Math    Physics     Bio     Algo    Archi   Sport   eng     total
0     A     50.0    60.0       60.0     50.0    60.0    70.0    80.0    430.0
1     B     55.0    64.0       63.0     52.0    62.0    72.0    82.0    450.0
2     C     5.5     8.4         9.3     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     23.2
3     D     NaN     NaN         NaN     22.0    42.0    62.0    82.0    208.0
4     E     6.0     8.8         9.6     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     24.4
5     F     NaN     NaN         NaN     24.0    44.0    64.0    84.0    216.0
```

TEST DATA

```
data_out = [
    ['A', 10,15,20,25,30,35,40],
    ['B', 11,16,21,26,31,36,41],
    ['C', 1.1,2.1,3.1],
    ['D', np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,11,21,31,41],
    ['E', 1.2,2.2,3.2],
    ['F', np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,12,22,32,42],
]
df=pd.DataFrame(data_out, columns=[ 'source', 'Math', 'Physics', 'Bio', 'Algo', 'Archi', 'Sport', 'eng'])
df['total'] = df.iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=1)

    source  Math    Physics     Bio     Algo    Archi   Sport   eng     total
0     A     10.0    15.0       20.0     25.0    30.0    35.0    40.0    175.0
1     B     11.0    16.0       21.0     26.0    31.0    36.0    41.0    182.0
2     C     1.1     2.1         3.1     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     6.3
3     D     NaN     NaN         NaN     11.0    21.0    31.0    41.0    104.0
4     E     1.2     2.2         3.2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     6.6
5     F     NaN     NaN         NaN     12.0    22.0    32.0    42.0    108.0
```